# How to present the past event in a best way in the context of having vomiting all day?

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english, past-tense, british-english

I am in a scenario where i have to inform my colleague that i was ill and i was suffering from vomiting , this is a past scenario as i am talking to him the next day. So how i can i present this to him.

```
1) I was suffering from vomiting all the day
2) I had vomiting the whole day
3) I did vomit all day
```

Was, had and did all are presenting past in this scenario, so how to understand that which is best suit for which scenario. As i am not a native speaker of english so i am not confirm about the correction of choices i write above.

Comment: I'd say "I was throwing up all day."

Comment: *Throwing up* is still on the way to make it in daily speaking here in India! ;) @StoneyB Trust me, I learned this term only 4 years back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As StoneyB says, the most natural way (for the native-speakers) would be...

> I was throwing up all day

'throwing up' is used for vomiting internationally.

In India, it's *still* not understood by many. So, your options are valid.

> I was suffering from vomiting all day 
>  I had vomiting all day

I'd not prefer telling `I did vomit all day` because when you emphasize using 'did' it's generally used to fill two contradictory sentences. Say--

> I took antiemetics, but I **did** vomit all day.

Comment: Can we write 'I vomited all day' instead of 'I did vomit all day'? If yes, then is it convey the same meaning as that of first two sentences written by OP.

Comment: yes, *I vomited all day* could be another option. It tells what it has to. @RuchirM